# Hibernate entities on the same database table for read and write

Tags: java, database, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

In our Spring Boot application we have two entities for the same table.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TBL_DATA")
@Immutable
public class DataReadEntity {

   // getters only
   ...
   // specific @OneToMany and @OneToOne relations only present in this entity
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "TBL_DATA")
@DynamicUpdate
public class DataWriteEntity {

  // getters and setters
}
```

DataReadEntity is used for data search only and is always used in a separate API. DataWriteEntity is used for fetching the whole object and updating it.

The problem is that hibernate still shows warning when updating DataWriteEntity with JPA criteria API
`SessionImpl - HHH000487: The query: [here goes update query] attempts to update an immutable entity: [TBL_DATA]` and update is successful.

So the question is - should we remove `@Immutable` annotation or just ignore this warning, because it is working as expected? It is considered that DataReadEntity will be never used for update operations (setters are not even implemented).

Spring Boot Application is working with default configuration - `spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default`.

Answer (score 1):

The underlying database entity is mutable but you want two entity representations for the same table. But hibernate knows which table it updates and is confused as it says in one place it is immutable.

I will not ignore the warnings because of this in the doc. It may be already ignoring the updates to `DataWriteEntity` silently and even if it doesn't, it might happen when you have a newer version.

> An immutable entity may not be updated by the application. Updates to an immutable entity will be ignored, but no exception is thrown. @Immutable must be used on root entities only.

- Why don't you create a `view` for `TBL_DATA` in database, and give it to `DataReadEntity` as table name and keep the `@Immutable` too? So hibernate is confused and you don't get warnings either and also you don't need to worry about unexpected behaviour when version changes?
- I also will caution against removing `@Immutable` because if you remove it, if users of that api modify the field intentionally for some other purpose thinking it does not have impact in database, but now there is no `@Immutable` so hibernate will propagate the change via dirty checking.

**Reference**

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/Immutable.html

Comment: Thank you. View might work, but I think it is an overhead and it is not convenient to extend if we need more data. Regarding other propositions - I wrote that all updates work fine (and in the future if not it will be tested) and read entity is intended for specific usage only. Problems might occur if we start using other instruments except JPA criteria API I guess and that's what I wanted to clarify.

Comment: I created a view and it worked in my case